# How to use cascade delete vs restrict for referential integrity with one-to-one record relationships?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-normalization, referential-integrity

I have a table CPT defined with

```
   TABLE cpt
(
   recid serial NOT NULL,
   ccpt text,
   cdesc text NOT NULL,
   ninsurance numeric(10,2),
   ncash numeric(10,2),
  ..... )
```

In which I wish to move the values ninsurance and ncash to another record in the cpt table. Therefore, I move these values to another table, cpt_invoice that is defined as

```
      TABLE cpt_Invoice
(
   recid serial NOT NULL,
   cpt_recid integer NOT NULL,      <--primary key from the cpt table.
   ninsurance numeric(10,2),
   ncash numeric(10,2),
   CONSTRAINT cs_cpt_invoice FOREIGN KEY (cpt_recid)
   REFERENCES cpt (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ..... )
```

Reducing the cpt table to:

```
   TABLE cpt
(
   recid serial NOT NULL,
   ccpt text,
   cdesc text NOT NULL,
  ..... )
```

So far so good. Now what is the best way to enforce the following contstraints:

1. Record in cpt_invoice can NOT be deleted if any record in cpt is referencing it, and
2. If a record in cpt is deleted, then the referenced record in cpt_invoice is also deleted.

Note: These tables are one-to-one meaning that each record in cpt will have one and only one record in cpt_invoice and visa versa.

The only idea that comes to mind is to add the primary key of cpt_invoice to the cpt table then on the cpt table do

> REFERENCES cpt_invoice (recid) ON DELETE RESTRICT

Does using a back-link make sense? How do others do this?

TIA

Comment: What are you asking about? Do you not find the clause `on delete restrict`?

Comment: @Str. Yes... but to my understanding that will only stop cpt_invoice from being deleted if it Is used anywhere. However, how then to implement #2 without causing a loop when the cpt record is deleted. i.e., I would like deletion of a cpt record to delete the cpt_invoice. These tables are one-to-one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the `cpt_Invoice` like this:

```
-- mixed case not recommended
create table TABLE cpt_invoice ( 
   recid serial NOT NULL,
   cpt_recid integer references cpt (recid) on delete cascade,
   ninsurance numeric(10,2)
   -- more...
  )
```

and you will be able to delete a record from `cpt` with automatic deletion of all dependent records in `cpt_invoice` (meeting requirement 2).

Your requirement 1 does not make sense: every record in `cpt_invoice` depends on one in `cpt`.

Edit: I don't know what your environment or application is, for more security look at [the SQL GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html) features, you can limit users to certain actions.

Comment: so do not  do any back-links to prevent explicit deletion of cpt_invoice? Thanks.

Comment: Delete is delete, you must know what you are doing. Remember, a delete of a cpt record deletes all dependent cpt_invoice records, what do you want to protect?

Comment: I want to maintain referential integrity by not orphaning cpt_invoice records when delete cpt is used; but I would like also to stop delete cpt_invoice from occurring when it is providing information to the parent cpt record....If this makes any sense (and it may be entirely ridiculous..)

Comment: cpt_invoice is always providing information to the parent. This is referential integrity, activated by `references table(col)`.